# Adobe Flash CS4 Professional, ActionScript 2.0

Tags: actionscript-2, flv, flash-cs4

I'm just a newbie in using CS4. I just want to ask "What is the code in order to move to the next frame when the FLV clip was finished playing?” I have a prediction that it might be:

```
on(complete){
  nextFrame();
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Is my code is wrong? The place where I put the code? The number of ActionScript? (1.0, 2.0, 3.0?) Any suggestion to make it correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If **flvplayback** is the name of the FLV Playback instance on stage.

```
var listener:Object = {};
listener.complete = function(e:Object):Void {
    nextFrame();
};
flvplayback.addEventListener("complete", listener);
```